# Bootstrap js selectpicker showing half keyword selection

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am using select picker of javascript and it is showing this. how can i fix this?
[Bootstrap js selectpicker showing half keyword selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwbFo.png)

```
<div class="col-md-3 float-left"> 
                        {{-- <label for="{{$static_filters_vendors_values['filter_name']}}">{{$static_filters_vendors_values['face_name']}}</label> --}}
                        <select name="{{$static_filters_vendors_values['filter_name']}}[]" id="{{$static_filters_vendors_values['filter_name']}}"  class="selectpicker form-control" multiple title="Select" style="text-align:center;">
                            @foreach($static_filters_vendors_values['options'] as $static_filters_vendors_values_keys=>$static_filters_vendors_values_values)
                                <option value="{{$static_filters_vendors_values_values['option_filter_name']}}" style="font-size:14px;">{{$static_filters_vendors_values_values['option_face_name']}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: you might want to add some height styling

Comment: yes! i want the text to show fully when i select an option